# Maintain image resolution in screen grab

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

In my app, the user is able to put stickers on top of a photo. When they go to save their creation, I do a screen grab and store it in a `UIImage`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

(where `self.mainView` has a subview `UIImageView` which holds the photo, and another subview `UIView` which holds the stickers).

I am wondering, is it possible to do a screen shot in this manner, and maintain the resolution of the aforementioned photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will 'flatten' two `UIImage`s into one while maintaining the resolution of the original image(s):

```
CGSize photoSize = photoImage.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(photoSize, NO, 0.0);

CGRect photoRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, photoSize.width, photoSize.height);
// Add the original photo into the context
[photoImage drawInRect:photoRect];
// Add the sticker image with its upper left corner set to where the user placed it
[stickerImage drawAtPoint:stickerView.frame.origin];

// Get the resulting 'flattened' image
UIImage *flattenedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The above assumes `photoImage` and `stickerImage` are both instances of `UIImage` and `stickerView` is a `UIView` with containing the `stickerImage` and thus will be able to use the `stickerView` frame to determine its origin.

If you have multiple stickers, just iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to save an image of your current view then this might help you.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.scrollView.contentSize);

[self.scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(finalImage.CGImage,
                                                   CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x,     scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                                              scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height));

UIImage *screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```